# The property of a modular conjugation operator

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

In Tomita-Takesaki theory, usually we first define a operator $S$ as
$$Sa|\Omega\rangle=a^\dagger|\Omega\rangle\,.$$
Then by using polar decomposition, we have
$$S=J\Delta^{1/2}\,,$$
where $J$ is an antiunitary operator called modular conjugation and $\Delta$ is an hermitian operator called modular operator. They have some properties:
$$J=J^*=J^{-1}\\J\Delta J=\Delta^{-1}\\J|\Omega\rangle=|\Omega\rangle;\,\Delta|\Omega\rangle=|\Omega\rangle\,.$$
I try to proof the relation $J\Delta^{1/2}a|\Omega\rangle=a^\dagger|\Omega\rangle$ directly from the algebraic properties of the antiunitary operator $J$ and the hermitian operator $\Delta$. My idea  is
$$J\Delta^{1/2}a|\Omega\rangle =J\Delta^{1/2}aJ|\Omega\rangle=(\Delta^{1/2} a)^\dagger|\Omega\rangle=a^\dagger\Delta^{1/2}|\Omega\rangle=a^\dagger|\Omega\rangle$$
Here I use a relation $JOJ=O^\dagger$ and the property that $\Delta$ is hermitian. The question is I am not sure if the relation $JOJ=O^\dagger$ is applicable. It is obviously contract to the relation $J\Delta J=\Delta^{-1}$. But I have found a similar statement in a lecture note from Takaseki, which says that the operator $J$ induces a transpose operation as $JO^*J=O^T$, for $O$ being a bounded operator on some hilbert space. If the relation of $J$ is true, then how to explain its contradiction to $J\Delta J=\Delta^{-1}$? If this relation is wrong, then how to proof the relation $J\Delta^{1/2}a|\Omega\rangle=a^\dagger|\Omega\rangle$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think the algebraic properties of these two operators (the 3 properties you wrote) uniquely  determine them, since those properties have no interplay with the reference von Neumann algebra of operators $a$. Thus your attempt to say something about the action of these operators on the vN algebra, starting from the three algebraic properties you wrote, is hopeless from scratch.

As a matter of fact, you may have two different von Neumann algebras which admit the  *same* cyclic and separating vector $\Omega$, thus defining two *different* couples of operators $\Delta$, $J$ that however satisfy the same algebraic properties you wrote. This is the case for operator algebras in different Rindler wedges in Minkowski space with the same cyclic vector $\Omega$ (Minkowski vacuum) in aQFT.

What we can say is however that, since $S\Omega=\Omega$ (taking $a=I$ in your first identity) we can write $Sa\Omega= SaS\Omega=a^\dagger\Omega$.
Noticing that $\Omega$ is separating by hypothesis, the right identity turns out to be $Sa= SaS=a^\dagger$ for all elements $a$ of the considered von Neumann algebra and not $JaJ=a^\dagger$.

Actually, in the latter  (generally wrong) identity, the left hand side stays in the *commutant* of the vN algebra which contains $a$, whereas the right-hand side stays in the algebra. The vN algebra and the commutant  may have trivial intersection (in case of factors). That is another reason why this identity is in general untenable.